# Sending multiple Content-Length headers in a HTTP POST request using Javascript

Tags: xss, javascript

I'm playing around with a self-xss bug that I believe I can escalate with a CSRF attack. However, the exploit relies on sending two identical `Content-Length` headers in a single POST request.

Essentially, I'm looking for a piece of Javascript code that will make the visitor's browser issue a request that looks like this:

```
POST /authenticate[xss payload]
Host: target.net
Content-Length: 4
Content-Length: 4

whatever=whatever
```

It doesn't matter if the Content-Length is correct or not - there just has to be two identical Content-Length headers.

Sorry if the answer to this is trivial, I hope you can cut an infosec n00b some slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-length` is a special header which can not be set using JavaScript in the first place, i.e. it is one of several [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). You might try [HTTP request splitting](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246929/HTTP%20Request%20Splitting) to bypass this restriction but it is unlikely to work on modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been looker into this a bit more, and I've found that it also works with `Content-Type` and `Content-Range` headers (which are not forbidden header names according to your source). Is it possibly exploitable then?

Comment: @weikop: A sane browser would not allow to set these headers multiple times since it would not make sense. But the browsers might also decide to merge these headers as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader): *"Each time you call setRequestHeader() after the first time you call it, the specified text is appended to the end of the existing header's content."*. In short: likely not.